# how can i access a object by key based off a string that has been split?

Tags: typescript

This works:

```
interface Lol {
  haha?: string;
}

let key: keyof Lol = 'haha';
let lol: Lol = {}
lol[key] = 'har har!';
```

but the code below gives me `type 'string' is not assignable to type '"haha"'.(2322)`

```
interface Lol {
  haha?: string;
}

let str = 'haha.waffle'
let key: keyof Lol = str.split('.')[0];
let lol: Lol = {}
lol[key] = 'har har!';
```

Why does this not work, how can I make it work?

Comment: You *have* to assert that `str.split(".")[0]` is `keyof Lol` with `as`. Some kind of assertion is necessary here.

Comment: TypeScript only knows that `split()` produces a `string[]`; it has no idea how long the resulting array might be or what might be in it.  If you want to merge in your own definition of `split` that knows more you could, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvqB3m) shows, but it's almost certainly overkill and it would be better for you to just tell the compiler that it's `keyof Lol` with a type assertion.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?